# Shorthand to Create an Array of Integers n1-n2

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Consider the following intuitive VBA command, which selects the first 10 slides of a PPT presentation:

```vb
ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)).Select
```

I would like to express this in more succinct form. For example

```vb
-- psuedo-code
ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(CreateRange(1,10)).Select
```

How can you do this with the VBA available in Powerponit?

Comment: I don't believe vba offers a create range function although you can certainly write such a function and add it to a "vba library" of your own with additional functions and subroutines (or otherwise, just put it in this workbook for use in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such build-in function in VBA, but it's quite simple to create your own:

```
Function createRange(fromVal As Long, toVal As Long) As Long()
    ReDim a(fromVal To toVal) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = fromVal To toVal: a(i) = i: Next
    createRange = a
End Function
```

... and voilà, your pseudo-code is no longer a pseudo-code

Comment: Wow! Very fast and clear answer

Comment: Very nice, very educational as well. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to use `ReDim a(1 To toVal - fromVal + 1 ) As Long` so that the indexing always starts at the same value.